# reading simple INI file with AS3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

What AS3 class should I use to read a simple property/ini file into memory to configure some settings such as colors easily for the project.

format could be

```
key=value <newline>
```

I like to access it with this kind of API:   trace ( Settings.get("key") )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this in AS3, but we have support for loading and parsing properties files in Spring ActionScript.

Here are the direct links to the sources:

- [Properties](https://fisheye.springframework.org/browse/~raw,r=184/se-springactionscript-as/spring-actionscript/trunk/core/src/main/actionscript/org/springextensions/actionscript/collections/Properties.as)
- [PropertiesParser](https://fisheye.springframework.org/browse/~raw,r=163/se-springactionscript-as/spring-actionscript/trunk/core/src/main/actionscript/org/springextensions/actionscript/collections/PropertiesParser.as) (used internally in Properties)

Answer (score 2):

I you can choose your format freely XML is very easy to deal with in actionscript3, it might not be perfect for super simple config files, but it's **extremely** easy to handle once you get it in.

This page looks to have a reasonable overview: http://dispatchevent.org/roger/as3-e4x-rundown/